# Browserify/Jadeify: require maps no longer supported

Tags: node.js, browserify

I am trying to use [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify)/[jadeify](https://github.com/substack/node-jadeify) on my ExpressJS project:

**`server.coffee`**

```
browserify = require "browserify"
jadeify = require "jadeify"

bundle = browserify()
    .use(jadeify(__dirname + "/client/jade/templates"))
    .addEntry(__dirname + "/public/js/app/main.js")
app.use bundle
```

**`main.coffee` (client side)**

```
$ = require "jquery"
jadeify = require "jadeify"

html = jadeify "test.jade", 
    title: "Hello World"
console.log html
```

What I got is:

```
Error: require maps no longer supported
    at Function.Wrap.require (/labs/Projects/Nodebook/node_modules/browserify/lib/wrap.js:410:15)
    at Function.module.exports.Object.keys.forEach.self.(anonymous function) [as require] (/labs/Projects/Nodebook/node_modules/browserify/index.js:158:28)
    at module.exports (/labs/Projects/Nodebook/node_modules/jadeify/index.js:53:16)
    at Function.Wrap.use (/labs/Projects/Nodebook/node_modules/browserify/lib/wrap.js:105:5)
    at Function.module.exports.Object.keys.forEach.self.(anonymous function) [as use] (/labs/Projects/Nodebook/node_modules/browserify/index.js:158:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/labs/Projects/Nodebook/server.coffee:55:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/labs/Projects/Nodebook/server.coffee:63:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.exports.run (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js:83:25)
    at compileScript (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:177:29)
```

Seems like the server does not want to start. How do I get this to work? I think the code is mostly the same as in the documentation. Whats wrong and how do I fix this?